# ошибка сегментирования linux

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

bool init_library(void *hdl, void(*print_hello)(const char *))
{
    hdl = dlopen("./libHello.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (NULL == hdl)
        return false;
    print_hello = (void(*)(const char *)) dlsym(hdl, "print_hello"); 
    if(NULL == print_hello)
        return false;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    void (*print_hello)(const char *);
    void *hdl;
    if(init_library(hdl, print_hello))
        print_hello("Vasya");
    else
        printf("Library was not loaded\n");
    dlclose(hdl);
    return 0;
}
```

компилю так gcc main.c -ldl -o exe
в итоге вылетает ошибка сегментирования.
даже если поставить printf("1\n"); в начале main - всё равно ошибка сегментирования.

код hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hello.h"

void print_hello(const char *name)
{

    printf("Hello, %s!\n", name);
}
```

код hello.h

```
#ifndef __HELLO__
#define __HELLO__

void print_hello(const char *name);

#endif
```

Makefile для libHello.so

```
libHello: hello.h hello.c
    gcc -shared hello.c -fPIC -o libHello.so
```

следующий код выполняется без ошибки

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
    void *hdl;
    hdl = dlopen("./libHello.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    void (*print_hello)(const char *);
    print_hello = (void(*)(const char *)) dlsym(hdl, "print_hello");
        print_hello("Vasya");
    dlclose(hdl);
    return 0;
}
```

компилю так же gcc main.c -ldl -o exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы изменяете локальную переменную.
Вне вызова функции указатель print_hello не меняется.
Можно объявить отдельный тип для указателя на функцию и передавать адрес переменной

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef void(*hello_ptr)(const char *);

bool init_library(void *hdl, hello_ptr* print_hello)
{
    hdl = dlopen("./libHello.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (NULL == hdl)
        return false;
    // сохраняем адрес функции
    *print_hello = (hello_ptr) dlsym(hdl, "print_hello"); 
    if(NULL == print_hello)
        return false;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    hello_ptr print_hello;
    void *hdl;
    if(init_library(hdl, &print_hello)) // передаем адрес, куда сохранять
        print_hello("Vasya");
    else
        printf("Library was not loaded\n");
    dlclose(hdl);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, привет вася напечаталось.
но теперь новая проблема:
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-close.c: 762: _dl_close: Assertion `map->l_init_called' failed!

Comment: Точно такая же проблема с хендлом библиотеки - изменяется лишь локальная переменная, hdl в функции main не меняется

Answer (score 1):

Если вместо `bool` возвращать из `init_library()` то, что реально от нее требуется -- указатель на открытую либу (т.е. результат `dlopen()`), то код несколько упростится.

Например, можно переписать так:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>


void * init_library(void **init_functon)
{
  void *hdl = dlopen("./libHello.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  if (hdl)
    if (!(*init_function = dlsym(hdl, "print_hello")))
      hdl = 0;
  return hdl;
}

int main()
{
  void (*print_hello)(const char *);
  void *hdl = init_library((void **)&print_hello);
  if (hdl) {
    print_hello("Vasya");
    dlclose(hdl);
  } 

  return hdl ? 0 : printf("Library was not loaded\n") != 0;
}
```

И обратите внимание, нельзя вызывать `dbclose()`, с нулевым указателем.

А если нравятся "однострочники", то `init_library()` можно изобразить и так:

```
void * init_library(void **print_hello) {
  void *hdl = dlopen("./libHello.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  return hdl && (*print_hello = dlsym(hdl, "print_hello")) ? hdl : 0;
}
```